# Simple product image in Config product - Magento 1.5

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.5 and have around 33,450 products on my site. 32000 are simple products attached to 1300 configurable products.

Now, the main problem is that I need to change the product image when my customer selects different color.

How can I do that?

I already installed http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html and this displays the prices of the simple products which is awesome. But I need it to display pictures of simple products as well.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `System > Configuration > SCP Products > SCP Cart > Show Configurable Product Image in Cart` and make sure that it's set to no.

Comment: Cags, thanks for answering. But I need the picture of simple product to change on the product itself and not on the cart. For eg if my customer selects GREEN color from the dropdown then the image of green should load from a simple product.

Did you get my point?

Answer (score 4):

The [EComDev Smart Color Selector](http://www.ecomdev.org/shop/color-selector.html) extension can do exactly that.  We're using it on a couple of sites and it works great.

Comment: Thanks EcomDev but I dont have this much budget to purchase this extension.

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic idea behind Color Swatcher:
1> Hide the dropdown/select field of color attribute using css(style="display:none")
2> Get all the associated color products and loop over them to display the thumbnail
3> Trigger the select field value based on the click on the related thumbnail
4> That's all

Real implementation is upto you.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Magepsycho, I went down your approach to get the images of the associated products and getting stuck at step 3. I have the thumbnails listed now but not clear how to get the click working? Any ideas please